# How do I show a .net balloon / tooltip while a treenode label is being renamed/edited?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

How do I show a .net balloon / tooltip while a treenode label is being renamed/edited?

I have been trying to achieve what happens when you try to create a new folder on Windows with an invalid character, for example "?" :

1. The invalid character isn't displayed, and
2. A balloon tool-tip pops up with the appropriate message.

A screenshot of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

A screenshot of what I currently have:

[image]

```
TreeNode^ newChild = foo;
newChild->BeginEdit();
```

Now as soon as the label gets highlighted, I would like the error checking to be in place, and not in AfterLabelEdit.

---

So my question has two parts:

1. How do I perform error checking during the label edit (instead of AfterLabelEdit), and
2. How do I display a balloon, with its position referenced towards the node that's being edited.

Comment: Why is this tagged c# and c++? Which language are you using (and don't say "both" or "either")?

Comment: @gunr2171 The code I'd like to implement this in is written in c++. However, I'd like to be able to use this feature with other parts of the project too, some of which are written in C#. I was wondering if there needs to be significant changes to the implementation, depending on the choice of those two.